# Karma ignores angular HTTP request in service

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am trying to test a service within karma.  The service is loading into the test but the `http` request is ignored.

The service contains:

```
console.log('test') //this is shown withing the karma console

$http.get("myjson.json").then(function(data) {
        this.data = data.data;
}); // this isn't executed
```

The test:

```
describe("Testing http request in service.", function() {
    beforeEach(module('myAPP'));

    var service, gHttp;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector,$rootScope , $httpBackend, myService) {
        service = myService;
        gHttp = $httpBackend;
    }));

    it('should work', function() {
    gHttp.flush();
    //Error: No pending request to flush !
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `$httpBackend` expectation first with `gHttp.expectGET('myjson.json')`